# Here's presumably the basic legal issue regarding "ChatGPT" which Prosus may wish to address. How would or should they?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

Say you type or say anywhere on any device "Melbourne, Australia", or almost any geography-like issue.

Google will immediately give you: text from Wikipedia.

Say you type or say anywhere on any device "iOS Swift UILabel placeholder position", or almost any software-like issue.

Google will immediately give you: text from Stack Overflow.

**But note that**

In the first example, Google screams "**answer from wikipedia.org**" before the text.

In the second case Google screams "**answer from stackoverflow.com**" before the text.

Now here's the issue. ChatGPT is google with dressing. (It simply does what google does, and adds dressing.)

If I type "iOS Swift UILabel placeholder position" at ChatGPT, in the overwhelming majority of cases, the result printed on the screen by ChatGPT, **has overwhelmingly been sourced from SO**.  (Exactly as when you type "iOS swift UILabel placeholder position" at google, since ChatGPT is google with dressing.)

**But in the ChatGPT case, it does not scream at you "from Stack Overflow".**

Will anything be done about this?

(Note, I could not care less about the stock price of either corporation: I just don't want SO's utility diminished, whilst I need it for my work.)

Comment: This whole question is based on a misconception of how a language model works. Sure, its training data may include SO contents, but it doesn't quote anything _verbatim_.

Comment: Also, _"ChatGPT is google with dressing."_ is comparing apples and oranges. Google indexes the internet and doesn't generate content, itself. ChatGPT is the __exact opposite__ in that it doesn't have access to the internet, and has to generate all output, by itself.

Comment: You're worried about attribution, based on the misconception that ChatGPT is copying text, verbatim. I'm no "ChatGPT fanboy", and your suggestion that I haven't read your question is rather toxic.

Comment: Based on the comments here alone, I feel that you're already not open to discussing this matter, and are on the side of "I'm right, you're wrong"; which is likely only going to attract downvotes and/or close votes. As has been stated, ChatGPT does *not* quote [so], or content from other sites, it uses the content it has been fed (which may well have been from [so]) to write it's own content. That's no different to some answers I've written in the past, where I've used things I have learned from [so] (in the past) the write an answer to a question. Am I ChatGPT?

Comment: Hi Larnu, you seem to have keyed on the first comment which mentions "quoting verbatim".  ChatGPT does not quote Stack Overflow, or content from other sites, it uses the content it has been fed (in fact, overwhelmingly from Stack Overflow) to write it's own content.  (ie: as you just said.)  Have you ever taken a photo of  a street in Germany - are you google street view?  When street view came in to being, it was (and is) a hot legal and social issue whether or not street view is a good or bad thing, whether or not it helps or hurts other parties.

Comment: So you're saying that I need to cite where I've learned to write all my content, as that's what you want ChatGPT to do? Well if so, this comment was brought to you by my parents and <redacted> primary school in <redacted> who taught me to read and write.

Comment: I don't know where I'm standing in those arguments, but I did manage with some trial and error, in finding *some* possible original sources for some of the output cgpt produce: Excerpt [one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55667859#55667859), [two](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55668097#55668097), [three](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55673627#55673627), [four](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55745717#55745717). I could go on, but you get the idea.

Comment: (cont2), while I said what I said above, that doesn't mean it can support generating attribution, as I mentioned in my own meta post on SO, it uses weight, randomized distribution, and other statistical properties to be able to generate "good" sounding and plausible output. Taking into account that it's probably also highly sorted by humans based on other existing AI-based company, you get the result that is presented before you. This means, that with some trial and error and some probability, you can indeed get the original output, just like with copilot, etc.

Comment: Larnu, *"So you're saying that I need to cite where I've learned to write all my content, as that's what you want ChatGPT to do?"*  Cheap "analogy hypotheticals" don't work at all. (As I pointed out with the street view example.) I have concern what an individual does.  Even under current, everyday existing, legal milieu, if C-G is writing *millions* of answers a day, making *billions* of dollars from doing so and is *entirely* achieving that using another resource (SO) - that's a fat ass lawsuit or government action.

Comment: ^ that's massively overestimating the programming use ChatGPT has... If it were that powerful, why isn't GitHub dominating the market with their CoPilot?

Comment: I have learned all my skills in what I am a (self proclaimed) SME of from other resources (much from [so], but not only), @Fattie , so should I be awaiting a "fat ass lawsuit" because I've provided over 3,700 answers?

Answer (score 10):

> But in the ChatGPT case, it does not scream at you "from stackoverflow".

It doesn't, because it doesn't need to.

It can't possibly quote its sources, because its sources are ***all of its training data.***

That training data (likely) includes Stack Overflow, but that's certainly not the only source.

Comment: (1) The source is absolutely overwhelmingly SO.  No neeed for a point 2 !

Comment: Worth noting that whether or not using the internet at large as training data constitutes plagiarism is a massive, ongoing discussion with passionate arguments on both sides (read: massive dogfights in comment sections). Not arguing against you, but it's a topic in active discussion far beyond SO

Comment: That's your opinion. That's not how a __language model__ works, @Fattie.

Comment: Strangely, when I make them, that is precisely how they work!  :) Cerbrus, looking at the "street view" example mentioned above.  It could be that (in that example) when street view came along, you were in the "it's obvious, there's nothing to discuss, street view is a social good, when I take a photo of berlin am I street view?, the case is closed, cameras exist, street view is AOK". (I personally often take the "it's obvious, there's nothing to discuss" view in societal issues!) Essentially, if so, "there's nothing to discuss"

Comment: Using the internet as a training data source isn't plagiarism. Generating output from that training data... Well, it's not like the model copies whole paragraphs at a time. So the discussion would be if it's plagiarism if the model determines the output needs to look like that one source that it found for the input.

Comment: `Using the internet as a training data source isn't plagiarism.`. Note that I don't disagree with your previous statement (not this one, the other ones), but for this particular point, "it depends". As Zoe better explained earlier, this is an ongoing discussion in various fields and communities.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine true, and I am particularly taking the "stock market / total self-interest" view: quite simply (in the programming field) ChatGPT lives off SO. End of story. (Discussions on the philosophical category of some software routines, whether copying etc, is irrelevant.)  In the programming field **ChatGPT lives off SO**. End of story. (Which is non-mysterious: google lives off SO, in the programming field.)  My only (selfish) concern is, will this harm SO (and hence me).

Comment: @NordineLotfi: Reading data isn't plagiarism.

Comment: @Cerbrus Language models do produce verbatim output, here is an example of Github's copilot doing exactly that with the quake invsqrt implementation: https://twitter.com/stefankarpinski/status/1410971061181681674?lang=en

Comment: @Fattie You're asserting that ChatGPT is literally copy-pasting whole answers, or whole blocks of code. That is simply not how language models work. Sure, it possible based on limited training data for the input, that the output is generated on only one or two sources, but then it's still just a word-for word generated output based on limited available sources.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy: Again, limited matching training data for the request. The request basically demanded a plagiarized copy. What'd you expect?

Comment: I'm not gonna argue about this here, since this isn't the right places. As mentioned I never said I thought you were wrong, at least looking at the total amount of arguments you used. I just said, "it depends". That can be extrapolated to an ongoing discussion, which as I said earlier, would be fruitless to have here.

Comment: yes, I also posted this in other meta.SO related posts for chatgpt and copilot. I also posted other possible excerpts but for chatgpt on a comment of this current post, feel free to look at it. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: @NordineLotfi: My point is that the "It depends" comes into play in the request / output generation. Training an AI is a different matter. No text is generated, it's just reading public data.

Comment: Cerbrus (I have endlessly *not* asserted that cgpt is copy pasting :) )  , I think the simplest summary is to repeat what I just said above. Presently (in the programming field) ChatGPT lives off SO. End of story. Semantics irrelevant. (Which is non-mysterious: google lives off SO, in the programming field, just as google lives off Wikipedia in the geography field.)  My only (selfish) concern is, will this harm SO (and hence me).

Comment: Again, SO is far from the only source of training data. @Fattie

Comment: you're giving it too much merit. read the two comments I posted on your post and maybe my meta post on this related subject. @Fattie

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy That "fast inverse square root" example is (also) quoted on Wikipedia... A website that's absolutely contained in CGPT's training data. In fact, if you'd google _"fast inverse square root"_, you'd see a heckload of results quoting _that exact snippet_. No wonder ChatGPT generates that code. It could be using 20 source sites to generate that exact output.

Comment: @Fattie The existence of language models doesn't hurt SO. The only damage happens when CGPT is fed back into Stack Overflow with no filter. It isn't an intelligent AI. It can degrade the content on Stack Overflow (which is why it's banned), and it can degrade its own training data (not our problem), but in its current state, it's a research artifact and not commercial. CGPT not being intelligent means it's incapable of competing with Stack Overflow. And when GPT at large can produce not just believable answers,  but consistently correct answers, [mission accomplished](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: copilot depends on other factors than what chatgpt uses. As I repeatedly mentioned (and other people said) this depends solely on the comments on the code you're trying to match. Using the license or anything part of the code will usually have a specific probability of giving you a near or exact 100% output of the training data. You could think of it as a `grep` version but with natural language support. It does mutate the output (eg change variable names, etc) but that's beside the point here.

Comment: @NordineLotfi another example (I mentioned elsewhere) is I now ask all my (difficult, "based on new releases from apple and such") questions to C-G, as a test.  (Which is no more mysterious that that, obviously, I ask google when a new hassle comes up.) Often ChatGPT has no answer (and - hence obviously - google has no answer).  In a couple cases, after time, someone on SO or myself has figured the answer and posted it on SO.  {As always happens in such cases, dozens of people/bots immediately copy the new answer around the net). **The answer then appears on CG** (and, obviously, google).

Comment: @Fattie: That's simply impossible, because ChatGPT is trained on data up to __2021__. It has no access to the internet.

Comment: I can't say anything about this since I never honestly noticed this. In a hypothetical setting, it could be possible for them to add new training data, but given the high computing loads they already have with users spamming it, adding another set of computing power used for "real-time" or near real-time training would be hard, even for them. @Fattie

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine **The existence of language models doesn't hurt SO** that's a staggeringly, amazingly,3 bold business assertion!!!!!  Prosus and C-G (and google) are advertising companies. (Obviously, Goog is the world's biggest advertising company, taking in 150 billion /annum in ads, SO is smaller, CG is getting started.)  If I get an answer from CG (ie "I see their ads"), rather than going to SO (ie, "I do not see their ads") and the **one and only reason the answer exists on CG** is SO's data, the damage can be measured in cents per human. Your comment is "nutty!"  :-)

Comment: @Fattie ChatGPT is in a _"Free Research Preview"_. It's not gonna stay free forever. It also generates plenty of low quality answers. SO traffic hasn't dropped since CGPT went public, so your scaremongering really is unwarranted.

Comment: @Cerbrus right, I'm aware of that paradox. My guess is they either just lied, or simply haven't mentioned they added a line of code last week to scrape again recently, or for sure, I made some mistake.  (I've been carefully trying to repro the experiment.)  Note that C-G evidently (and this is weird in a way) gives you different answers to the identical text input at different times (well that has been my finding). Good point.

Comment: I feel its unrealistic to describe it as scaremongering, and, every "paradigm - whatever - changing" new societal Thing starts small.

Comment: Bye for now, all.

Comment: to your latter point, this isn't weird. Remember, most if not all statistical learning algorithms does just that, they depend, either when training or after, on random distribution. You can see that with RNN and other similar ones as well unless you use a deterministic way, but in some cases, it might not yield the best output. @Fattie

Comment: There's no paradox, there's no lie. The AI __isn't retrained__ on live data. _"they added a line of code last week to scrape again recently"_ It's not that simple.

Comment: @Fattie " Prosus and C-G (and google) are advertising companies" - So? Ad blocks exist too, which is arguably a bigger  threat (resource costs plus no income is a net negative). I'm also gonna have to side with Cerbrus. This sounds far more like fearmongering than anything else. OpenAI is aiming for making CGPT a paid product, and free alternatives for anything generally get more attention. Even then, OpenAI's products (for the time being) have a massive disclaimer that accuracy isn't guaranteed, and all output has to be vetted. The CGPT ban and the data points leading up to it (1/2)

Comment: have demonstrated that people don't validate the content it produces. It'll take a while for people to realize it isn't as good as human-produced content, and especially when it's paid, it'll hardly represent a dent in traffic. Again, the only point when AI will represent a true threat to today's model of the internet is the day AI is actually intelligent. We aren't there yet, and when we get there, again, mission accomplished. The internet will see another shift, companies adapt, people adapt, and a new normal resumes

Comment: [Some describe](https://odysee.com/@TheLinuxExperiment:e/microsoft-isn't-the-enemy-of-linux-and:3) [Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) as a *copyright laundering machine* (at 08 min 55 secs).

Answer (score 3):

ChatGPT might generate answers that are verbatim (or near verbatim) copies of existing answers, but for the same reason Stack Overflow [does nothing about scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343405) they can't do anything about ChatGPT not attributing answers.

The reason for this is that Stack Overflow does not own the copyright to the content, which remains with the original author. If you find ChatGPT quoting content you own verbatim your recourse would be to [contact OpenAI](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6614161-how-can-i-contact-support) yourself.

Comment: As mentioned extensively the issue is unrelated to "verbatim".

Comment: That's pretty significant when attribution is concerned... Attribution, which is the core issue you seem to raising here...